# I was trying to create an object model for my Flask app, using Flask-alchemy but its not working after inheriting the database.Model class

Tags: python, database, object, flask, inheritance

I was trying to create a model class for BlogPosts in my database, and I passed in the database.model into my class name so as to inherit all its modules, but rather I am getting an error telling me that database.Column is an unresolved reference.
Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='N/A')
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Blog Post' + str(self.id)
```

all db. are not working including db.Column, db.String, db.Integer they all return unresolved variable.

Comment: Could you post the full output?

Comment: No output, but editor highlight the column in  db.Column and everything i tried to inherit from the db class and when i put my mouse over it to know what is going on its giving me warning that the variable Column is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with this versions on python 3.6:

- SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
- Flask==1.1.1
- Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1

And works fine:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='N/A')
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Blog Post' + str(self.id)

print(db.Model)
print(db.Column)
print(db.String)
print(db.Integer)
```

Results in:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Model'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Integer'>
```

Make sure you have all the python packages installed.

Comment: I am using python 3.9 this thing is about to take my life, I don't really have any idea on what to do, its just too stupid

Comment: python 3.9.1 and flask 2.2